# ASP/.NET : Entity (LINQ) : ModelContainer not recognised as a Namespace

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have built the Entity Data Model and I can see the tables that I have chosen out of the Database to work with which is named Model.

It now lets me use:

`using Model;`

However, when I then want to `ModelContainer db;` I get this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ModelContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I have done as much research as I can, double checked I set it up correctly but still do not understand why I am getting this error? I shouldn't have to use: `using MySQL;' or any other of such...

Thank-you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `ModelContainer` is part of the `Model` namespace?

Comment: I've looked into the Model Namespace and it does not exist... You're correct, can anyone explain why it does not exist? It existed in my Lessons and I never manually created it.